# New Macbook won't run Tizen Emulator

Tags: macos, tizen, tizen-emulator

I was recently upgraded to a new Macbook Pro (Running High Sierra 10.13.6 (17G65)) at work and I am unable to run the Tizen emulator.  I had no issue on my previous Macbook, but I now cannot get past "Booting the kernel".  I have fully uninstalled and re-installed Tizen studio with no luck.  Any ideas?

[Emulator hangs on Booting the kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Clan4.png)

Comment: Check all (emulator) requirements fulfilled accurately https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/download/installing-tizen-studio/prerequisites

Answer (score -1):

Late last night I downgraded the HAXM version to haxm-macosx_v6_2_1 and it is now working